# Returning a string array using only an iterator

Tags: java

Noob programmer here. I'm having difficulty trying to figure out where my mistake is in the code below. I'm trying to return a string array using only an iterator.

I know my code logic might be incorrect right after my second if statement where I call `matchingProv[] = provinceName;` Not sure if I'm supposed to put my int index variable within the square brackets? Not sure if I'm even asking the right question

Thank you for your help

```
public String[] getProvincesWhoseNameStartsWith(char letter) {

    String[] matchingProv;
    String str = String.valueOf(letter);
    ProvinceTerritory temp = null;
    int index = 0;

    if(provinces != null) {
        Iterator<ProvinceTerritory> provinceIT = provinces.iterator();

        while(provinceIT.hasNext()) {
            temp = provinceIT.next();

            if(temp != null && temp.getName() != null && temp.getName().startsWith(str)) {
                String provinceName = temp.getName();
                matchingProv[] = provinceName;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
    return matchingProv;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `provinces`? Because an array has a fixed `length`. You must initialize your `matchingProv` array with the desired output size.

Comment: I should have mentioned that sorry. provinces is my array list of type ProvinceTerritory. I've got 13 objects in my array list

 provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("British Columbia", 4400057));

Comment: You dont know how many provinces start with the char you are providing as an input , so you need to have a list, later you can convert that to string array to return it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not aware of how many provinces start with the char you provided in the input to the method , so we can not create a string array because it needs the size of array while declaring it. What you can do is create an ArrayList and store data in that and and while returning you can convert to string array and return from the method. I have done some modification for the same in the code below:

```
public String[] getProvincesWhoseNameStartsWith(char letter) {

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
            String str = String.valueOf(letter);
            ProvinceTerritory temp = null;
            int index = 0;

            if(provinces != null) {
                Iterator<ProvinceTerritory> provinceIT = provinces.iterator();

                while(provinceIT.hasNext()) {
                    temp = provinceIT.next();

                    if(temp != null && temp.getName() != null && temp.getName().startsWith(str)) {
                        String provinceName = temp.getName();
                        al.add(provinceName);
                    }
                    
                    }
                }
            String[] matchingProv = new String[al.size()];
            matchingProv = al.toArray(matchingProv);
            return matchingProv;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Harmandeep, thank you! Do you mind explaining what the index++; does? And how it works? Does it increment the while loop? Nested loops still confuse me quite a bit

Comment: We need not do index++, since you are using the iterator , hence it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

For this coding works you need:

1. Allocate memory for storing `provinceName`, using the `new` keyword, for example, if you need store maximum 10 names, `String[] matchingProv = new String[10];`.
2. Store `provinceName` in memory allocated using `matchingProv[index] = provinceName`, use `index` for access specific position of array and store the name, the `index` value must be maximum 9 otherwise you cause overflow of array. For my sample, is valid `index` value on interval of 0 to 9.

Comment: But we dont know the length of the array at the start  , there could be more matching provinces ,right?

Comment: Exactly @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, the example it's just to keep code of @koostra without others modifications, but using `ArrayList` (for example) instead array, allows dynamic length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two passes if you can only use an `Iterator`. First to count the matches, second to copy to the output. Something like,

```
public String[] getProvincesWhoseNameStartsWith(char letter) {
    int count = 0;
    if (provinces != null) {
        Iterator<ProvinceTerritory> provinceIT = provinces.iterator();

        while (provinceIT.hasNext()) {
            ProvinceTerritory temp = provinceIT.next();
            if (temp != null && temp.getName() != null
                        && letter == temp.getName().charAt(0)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    String[] matchingProv = new String[count];
    if (count > 0) {
        Iterator<ProvinceTerritory> provinceIT = provinces.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ProvinceTerritory temp = provinceIT.next();
            if (temp != null && temp.getName() != null
                        && letter == temp.getName().charAt(0)) {
                matchingProv[i] = temp.getName();
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return matchingProv;
}
```

Or, if using Java 8+, use a `map` and `filter` operation and collect to a temporary `List` and then return a `String[]`. Like,

```
return provinces.stream().map(ProvinceTerritory::getName)
            .filter(s -> s.charAt(0) == letter)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: No need to collect to a list and then convert to an array.  You can replace `.collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0])` with `toArray(String[]:new)`.

Answer (score 0):

Now if i'm trying to return the ProvinceTerritory[]. How would I do that vs returning a regular String[]?

public ProvinceTerritory[] getMoreProvincesWhoseNameContains(String substring) {

```
    ProvinceTerritory[] names = new ProvinceTerritory[13];
    ProvinceTerritory temp = null;
    int index = 0;

    if(provinces != null) {
        Iterator<ProvinceTerritory> provinceIT = provinces.iterator();

        while(provinceIT.hasNext()) {
            temp = provinceIT.next();
            if(temp != null && temp.getName() != null && temp.getName().contains(substring)) {
                names[index] = temp.getName();
            }
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```